# trying to config a git server with some clients

Tags: git, web, ssh, config

I'm trying to configure git service on my server.

To do that I've started configuring the server, where all my files are. All my files are in a folder called folder1, so I've just set git init on that folder. A .git appeared. Now I've add/commited this folder to get ready / confirm changes. Now git has a first snapshot of my project. Next step I've done is to clone the project into version_1.git from folder1 with the --bare:

```
git clone --bare folder1 version_1.git
```

I realiced then that I've just init the version_1 folder but with .git files without any project real files.

What I'm trying to know is how to work now into the project with 2 developers.

In the client I've already configure the user.name and the user.email with config. Also I've set the remote parameter to the ssh in where i'd like to place the project with the command: `git remote add project1 ssh://username@server/~/folder1/version_1.git`.

I tried to follow the [book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/) but after reading the 4 first chapters I don't take in clear how to do that

Thanks in advice